# Old sewing machine motor filter/capacitor schematic/wiring

Tags: capacitor, filter, identification, universal-motor

I have an old Pfaff 97 sewing machine that suddenly started to run at full speed regardless of the pedal input.

I disassembled and checked the foot pedal and it is working perfectly.

I took out the motor and found a strange capacitor/filter. Can anyone help me decipher the schematic so I can replace it using individual capacitors?

The black and white wires got shorted and this is the problem.

(from my understanding of German language: "grau" = grey; "gemeins. Pol weiss" = common pole white; "sw" = black; I have no idea what b in a circle with the grounding symbol means as the motor has no grounding)

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like a dual start/run cap. in metal film that are shorted

Comment: Got a dremel??? Open it up and see how it works.

Comment: grau is grey, wiess is white, and sw is black, if that helps.

Comment: @KyleB Good point, I will open it at some point. But for now, after writing the question, I realised that if I  disconnect the white wire it may work. And it works indeed. I am not sure if this setup will do any damage to the motor on the long run.

Comment: Generally the caps exist for only 1 of 2 purposes... They are 'motor start' caps (some AC motors require this) or they are for electromagnetic noise filtering.  If it works by disconnecting the wire, likely then they are indeed for noise purposes.  If you aren't having problems (i.e. blowing away your neighbors radio or your own WiFi router), then just move on, all is OK  IMHO.     No risk of damage.   If they are start caps, there is risk of damage in that you can apply power to the motor, but it won't turn.  It'll start smoking pretty quick after that, and should be obvious to turn it off.

Comment: I forgot to mention it is an universal motor so I doubt it needs any start caps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

[image]

I believe that you are correct. It is a universal motor and the capacitors are used to filter the noise of the commutator and the rheostat sliding contact.

Comment: from the label I assume there are 4 capacitors inside: 0.06uF, 2 x 2000pf and 0.02uf but I may be wrong

Comment: I think the 2 x 2000 pf caps are connected from gray and black to the capacitor enclosure case which is assumed to be ground and probably would be ground if the metal parts of the machine were grounded.

Answer (score 0):

About:

> Can anyone help me decipher the schematic so I can replace it using individual capacitors?

I found [here](http://sewingnz.blogspot.com/2012/11/sewing-machine-interference-capacitor.html) this quad-capacitor showing the diagram more clearly - just in case, I marked the capacitance values if you decide to follow them in commercial values:
**2x 2200pF + 1x 22nF + 56nF**.
Minimum voltage should be 400V, better if 600~630V.

[image]

Other site shows [different versions](https://www.quiltingroomwithmel.com/2016/11/electric-foot-controls-vs-electronic.html) of Foot control pedal and [this one discusses](https://oldsingersewingmachineblog.com/2012/02/22/the-vintage-singer-foot-pedal-button-controller-sewing-motor-controller-whatever-more-about-it/) exactly function of the capacitor (green highlighter), the problem you described (red highlighter) and their proposed solution (in yellow); but instead of simply removing it.

Instead of completely removing the capacitor, I would prefer to use a *single capacitor as a **1nF** x 600V ~ 1KV (ceramic or film)*, or even better if can find: a *Safety Class X2 of 1nF x 400V*, if available to you.

[image]